# Jest/Supertest errors with TypeError: app.address is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

Firstly, I have tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986863/mocha-api-testing-getting-typeerror-app-address-is-not-a-function) - didn't help to resolve, the accepted answer didn't resolve my issue.

I am trying to test my API endpoints with Jest/Supertest. Starting with a simple /test endpoint. However when I run the tests, I get:
`TypeError: app.address is not a function`.

`app.js`:

```
...
// Set server (default to 3000)
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  // Start server
  const server = http.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    logger.info(`Worker ${process.pid} running on ${app.get('port')} in ${app.get('env')} mode`);
  });

  module.exports = server;
...
```

`app.test.js`:

```
const server = require('./app');
const supertest = require('supertest');
const request = supertest(server);

it('Gets the test endpoint', async (done) => {
  // Sends GET Request to /test endpoint
  const res = await request.get('/test');
  done();
});
```

Test run output:

```sh
FAIL  ./app.test.js
  ✕ Gets the test endpoint (24 ms)

  ● Gets the test endpoint

    TypeError: app.address is not a function

      14 | it('Gets the test endpoint', async (done) => {
      15 |   // Sends GET Request to /test endpoint
    > 16 |   const res = await request.get('/test');
         |                             ^
      17 |
      18 |   // ...
      19 |   done();
```

Any input would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Supertest takes the *app*, not the server. You don't need to listen, it sets up the port for you (that's one of the benefits - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62992056/3001761). I'd recommend splitting up the app and the server parts, as I've done here https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/tree/1567d269b8afe5d93408202900ac0ac1473fd89e/server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment from [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) above was the correct answer:

> Supertest takes the app, not the server. You don't need to listen, it sets up the port for you (that's one of the benefits - stackoverflow.com/a/62992056/3001761). I'd recommend splitting up the app and the server parts, as I've done here https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/tree/1567d269b8afe5d93408202900ac0ac1473fd89e/server