# How to implement @types/supertest

Tags: typescript, supertest

I'm about to implement some API tests using Supertest and Typsecript.  Problem is, I'm new to typescript.  I've installed both superstest and @types/supertest from npm, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to make reference to @types/supertest.  In my below code, my DIE (VS Code) is not happy about "app" or "applicationJson".

```
import * as request from 'supertest';

getToken: async function(tokenUsername, tokenPassword) {
    return await request(app).post(
        `https://foobar/login`,
        { accept: applicationJson }, 
        {
            Email: tokenUsername,
            Password: tokenPassword,
        },
        envConfig.BaseUrl);
}
```

What on earth am I missing?

Comment: Where _did_ you expect those things to be defined? app is supposed to be **your app**, which SuperTest can't be exporting.

Comment: hmm, so if I'm hitting an external endpoint - "app" would be not there?  to request().post()  ??

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62992056/3001761 for the purpose of SuperTest, [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) include how to hit an arbitrary URL. This isn't a types problem; your _values_ are undefined.